# All redirects to infinite loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, infinite-loop

I want to redirect all request except like .html  .js .jpg etc... For example www.mydomain.com/products should go to /index.php?p=cats&s=cars    but www.mydomain.com/myproduct.html should go to www.mydomain.com/index.php?p=prod&s=myprod

my all redirects works fine but there is a problem. if i request without query string it's fall to infinitive loop
my code is here. is there any solution for infinitive loop?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=cats&s=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?p=prod-detail&p=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ index.php?p=cats&s=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ index.php?p=prod-detail&p=$1 [L,QSA]
```